# Laravel project cannot create using composer in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: laravel-5

i want to create laravel project by this command in ubuntu 16.04

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.2.*"

project does not create and show this error-

[ErrorException]
  mkdir(): Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

In Linux machine, user must have to take super user or root permission to write files in disk, if you are not in your user space. So use `sudo` command at the beginning since you are using ubuntu 16.04.

```
sudo composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog_5.2.
```

Don't give any space in project directory name, for that I showed under score `_`

Note: if you see your project folder is locked sign icon, then change the user by using this command:

```
sudo chown -R username blog_5.2./
```

Otherwise you may face problems on some third party commands. See more details 
https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-to-install-untrusted-packages-safely.md